# What am I? (My first original riddle)

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

I am very new to writing riddles and such, so bear with me if this one is terrible.

> My prefix is the dream of many, but the life of very few.
>
> If you were my infix, you'd wish that you further grew.
>
> My suffix is the crutch of many who wish to speak their minds
>
> If you view me in the dark, a glow I leave behind
>
> What am I?

This one requires a bit of outside knowledge, but anybody with a high school degree has heard of this at some point.

I will add hints every once in a while if nobody has gotten it yet. Good luck, and feedback is very much appreciated!

First Hint:

> Though soft and silky I might seem, I'd warn you to beware;
>  Should you be exposed to me, you might start losing hair.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "crutch of many"? (non-native speaker) "Crutch of someone" meaning "something that someone could lean on"?

Comment: "To use (something) as a crutch" is also used metaphorically to refer to something that provides support (either physical or psychological), often with the implication that the measure is crude or temporary.

Comment: That is the part I had the most difficulty wording, especially if I wanted to keep my rhyme looking pretty. The suffix here is something that many people rely on to a fault, as someone might rely on a crutch when they don't need it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Welcome to Puzzling SE!

I'm pretty sure you're:

> [Actinium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinium)

My prefix is the dream of many, but the life of very few.

> Many people dream of acting, yet few are successful

If you were my infix, you'd wish that you further grew.

> I'm sure if you were "tini", you'd wish you were bigger

My suffix is the crutch of many who wish to speak their minds

> Umm...

If you view me in the dark, a glow I leave behind

> [image: Actinium Picture] 
>  Actinium glows when active

And for the hint:

> Actinium has a soft and silky look, and exposure to radioactive elements [can cause hair loss](https://toxnet.nlm.nih.gov/cgi-bin/sis/search/a?dbs+hsdb:@term+@DOCNO+7411)

Comment: Bravo! Hopefully it wasn't too easy

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure about this at all but I'll guess

> Promethium?

My prefix is the dream of many, but the life of very few.

> A lot of people want to be a pro (professional) in their field but some never reach that stage in the end.

If you were my infix, you'd wish that you further grew.

> Methi seeds or the plant itself?

My suffix is the crutch of many who wish to speak their minds.

> Um as in "Ummmm... I think"

If you view me in the dark, a glow I leave behind.

> It's a glowing radioactive element?

For the hint

> I'm not sure if it's soft or not but to be exposed to the radioactive element, surely you'll be expected to loose a lot more than hair.

Comment: So incredibly close, and mostly everything you said could easily apply. However, Promethium is not characteristicly soft.

Comment: I did a little more research and I think it's Actinium, isn't it? EDIT: Welp, never mind  someone already beat me to it.

Comment: Post a new answer, I am interested in seeing your reasoning

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> Radium

My prefix is the dream of many, but the life of very few.

> Everybody wants to be rad, but most people only reach tubular, mondo, or outrageous.

If you were my infix, you'd wish that you further grew.

> Lowercase i wishes it were I.

My suffix is the crutch of many who wish to speak their minds

> Um.. um.. let me just um.. say um.. this one um.. thing.

If you view me in the dark, a glow I leave behind

> Radioluminescent paint uses radium-226.

The hint:

> Radium is soft, yet radioactive.

Comment: I didn't think this would work with so many elements... but nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

Similar to some other answers, are you

> **THORIUM**?

My prefix is the dream of many, but the life of very few.

> **THOR** is dreamy, but only a handful people have ever claimed the title

If you were my infix, you'd wish that you further grew.

> **I** might wish I were bigger?

My suffix is the crutch of many who wish to speak their minds

> **"UM"** is an common interjection when people are speaking

If you view me in the dark, a glow I leave behind

> Thorium can glow

Hint:

> Thorium is soft (but not sure how 'silky' it is) and radioactive.

Comment: I love this answer, it definitely makes sense. Simon got the answer I was thinking of, but +1 for a new take on it!

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be my super-stretch answer of the day, but are you

> ULTRAVIOLET (light)

My prefix is the dream of many, but the life of very few.

> Not many people are ULTRA-rich

If you were my infix, you'd wish that you further grew.

> Stretch #1: if you further grew by one letter, you could be RAVIOLI instead of "RAVIOL"

My suffix is the crutch of many who wish to speak their minds

> Stretch #2: if you wanted to speak your mind, I should LET you speak it.

If you view me in the dark, a glow I leave behind

> Stretch #3: UV radiation can glow in the dark...?

Hint:

> Exposure to UV can lead to hair loss.

This seems like I hopped on a train headed the wrong direction, and refuse to disembark...

Comment: You are in the right ballpark, and certainly the right subject in school. Not quite what I had in mind though

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this even qualifies as a stretch, but is it

> some kind of a mollusc

since some kinds of them are

> glowing in the dark (bioluminescent)

and the suffix is

> usc (as in the United States Constitution)

which is something a lot of people refer to as justification for saying something?

Comment: I like the explanation, but how do you explain the prefix?